# function: char* differs in levels of indirection from int expression

Tags: c, function

I am working on a function where the user enters information, and I want that information to copy to an array.  Here is what I have so far:

```
struct drone_info /* structure declaration */
{
    int number; /* drone number */
    int type; /* drone type */
    char pilot_name[30]; /* pilot name */
};

struct drone_info drone[100]; /* declare array for struct */

void add_a_drone();

void add_a_drone()
{
    int number; /* drone number */
    int type; /* drone type */
    char pilot_name[30]; /* pilot name */

    printf("\nPlease enter the drone number."); /* prompt user for drone number */
    scanf("%d", &number); /* scan drone number */
    printf("\nPlease enter the drone type."); /* prompt user for drone type */
    scanf("%s", &type); /* scan drone type */
    printf("\nPlease enter the pilot name."); /* prompt user for pilot name */
    scanf("%s", &pilot_name); /* scan pilot name */

    strcpy(drone[number - 1].number); /* error occurs here */
    strcpy(drone[type - 1].type, type);
    strcpy(drone[pilot_name].pilot_name, pilot_name);
    printf("\nThe new drone has been added successfully.\n\n");

    number++; /* increment drone number by 1 */
```

Comment: Why do you increment the drone number if the user enters it each time?

Comment: I was thinking the drone number would increment as new drones are added, but you are right - it isn't necessary if the user is inputting it.

Comment: Well, you could use two different variables. One for the array index, which increments, and another is the drone number that the user enters. Why bother putting the number into the struct if it's just the same as the array index.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `strcpy` (like the name implies) is only for *strings*, and not other data types. You also should use a consistent `size_t` or `int` when indexing the array, and never a `char*`.

So these lines:

```
strcpy(drone[number - 1].number); /* error occurs here */
strcpy(drone[type - 1].type, type);
strcpy(drone[pilot_name].pilot_name, pilot_name);
```

really should be

```
drone[current].number = number; /* no more error */
drone[current].type = type;
strcpy(drone[current].pilot_name, pilot_name); /* you can still use strpy here! */
```

where `current` is an `int` that keeps track of the current `drone`.

Comment: `current` is apparently `number - 1`.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I initially thought, but the fact that they increment `number` at the end of the function leads me to believe they have one variable name for what's supposed to be two different concepts. As it stands now, I think it's ambiguous what the intention is, so I just used `current`.

Comment: Now I get this error:  C4996 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: @sjoco Microsoft deprecated many of the standard library functions because they can cause buffer overruns. `scanf` is safe as long as you pass a buffer size (e.g. `scanf("%29s", pilot_name)`), but `scanf_s` requires the size instead of making it optional `scanf_s("%29s", pilot_name)`. If you're not too worried about buffer overruns, just write `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before your `#include <stdio.h>`.